# Excel date column value on which I can filter

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have date_added column in my Excel sheet with sample data as below:

[image]

I need to convert the rows which have data in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format

1. I need to remove '/' and replace it with '-' sign for this particular column (row 4,5,6,7,8)
2. I need to convert mm-dd-yyyy format to dd-mm-yyyy format (row 4,5,6,7,8). Please note month is populated as 5,7 and not as 05,07
3. I want to filter on this column after conversion. Now I am unable to filter on this column because date which are in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format are taken as unique value.

Kindly help.

Comment: do you mean using the macros with VB right? or just using the excel menu interface?

Comment: Check the comments as well as the answer at the duplicate question.